# does pushSubscription.endPoint change over time?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I am trying to send a push notification to multiple users. On the first load of a page, I will subscribe the user for Push API and gets the EndPoint and storing that in Database for sending push notifications.

Do i need to continuously check for PushSubscription.Endpoint and update the database? Or it is fixed?

Answer (score 2):

The endpoint can change, for example the subscription can expire (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PushSubscription/expirationTime).

You don't have to continuously check if it changes though, there's an event that is triggered when there is a change: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/pushsubscriptionchange.

Also look at the related question about how to force triggering the event: [How can I test pushsubscriptionchange event-handling code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36602136/how-can-i-test-pushsubscriptionchange-event-handling-code).